# How to install Eclipse EE on ubuntu?

Tags: configuration, eclipse

I tried to install eclipse EE on top of regular eclipse downloaded through ubuntu store - after the installation eclipse won't open.
tried installing eclipse ee through .deb, `"An error has occurred. See the log file /home/v/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/1631686693143.log."` error is produced, I tried deleting .metadata from workspace, no use.
Don't ubuntu 20.04 users use Eclipse EE?

Sequence of steps and errors

- Opening eclipse ee downloaded from the web
- Error : An error has occurred.
    See the log file /home/v/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/1631688631777.log.
- 1631688631777.log :

```
!SESSION 2021-09-15 12:20:31.324 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=11.0.11
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2021-09-15 12:20:32.488
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-09-15 12:20:32.503
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2021-09-15 12:20:32.528
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2021-09-15 12:20:32.529
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2021-09-15 12:20:32.529
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-09-15 12:20:32.532
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Comment: This question should include additional diagnostic info.  Edit your question and include 1) the command you used; 2) the complete output; and 3) the contents of the log file that is referenced. So that we can parse the information please format your post using [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) so that line breaks are preserved and it can be distinguished from the surrounding text.

Comment: What do you mean by "eclipse EE"? Eclipse for Java or what? How exactly it was installed?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, I was referring to Eclipse for Java EE development, I installed through various methods each time(.tar.gz file from official website, through terminal, through ubuntu store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and answers. The installation did work at last. I don't know what exactly worked, but here are the steps I followed, for posterity.

After installing and uninstalling several times, I followed [this tutorial](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/04/13/step-by-step-eclipse-java-ee-on-ubuntu-20-04-installation/) after which I got a different error, about a missing dependency.

I again purged and removed eclipse through terminal and tried installing eclipse through official website and it worked this time.

I don't think this makes a difference, but this time I installed eclipse in a new directory in downloads/ folder.

I think due to trying to install multiple times, on each attempt I fulfilled a different requirement like specifying jvm,... I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the downloaded eclipse files over the ubuntu-store installed version? That is not a good idea.

The different versions of eclipse that you can download are actually the same version of eclipse, with a different set of plugins and addons installed. So you can either

- Install different versions of eclipse next to each other, each with a different purpose. Just download a full bundle from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ and extract it in a folder.
- Install your requirements in the ubuntu-installed eclipse. Like https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-enterprise-java-and-web-developer-tools for Java EE

Comment: I removed each eclipse version before trying to install other one through other method through purge and remove commands, so I don't think the files were copied over one another, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For reproducible way I would to recommend to install Eclipse Java EE using [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make

umake ide eclipse-jee
```